# Что делать если год(ы) назад я принял вопрос, а он - не очень точен?

Tags: обсуждение, нормы-поведения

Уважаемые коллеги! Уже который раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой:

1. Я задал вопрос пять лет назад.
2. Иван Иванов ответил на вопрос пять лет назад.
3. Я, скрепя сердце, и не поняв до конца ответа - принял ответ.
4. Голосователи насовали ответу Ивана Иванова +3 и больше.
5. Прошло пять лет, у меня грохнулась пара проектов, из-за того, что Иван Иванов мне ответил не в полном объеме, не точно, не описав какие-то важные подводные камни и так далее.
6. Я повзрослел, полез в docs, на англоязычный SO и понял, что правильный ответ должен выглядеть по-другому.

Поймите коллеги, не в репе дело. О других молодых разработчиках думаю. Могут с этим ответом, принятым, да с репой +10 на грабли наступить.

И тут, для корректного поведения хочется спросить сообщество, что правильно делать:

1. Дать самому правильный ответ - и поставить себе галку, - по моему плохо. Обижает Ивана Иванова, который 15 минут корпел, чтобы дать мне ответ пять лет назад. Иван Иванов потом ответку кидает - минусует что-то. Жалко человека, который ранее помог.
2. Написать в комментарии - народ не увидит.
3. Исправить ответ Ивана Иванова - бывает, что исправлять приходится капитально. Да и Иван Иванов с такими правками может не согласится. И зрителю со стороны не будет видна конструктивная дискуссия.
4. Может быть лучшая стратегия, прямо в своём вопросе писать UPDATE: и свой ответ? Авось потомки оценят? Но минус в том, что формат сайта предполагает - вопрос отдельно, ответ отдельно.
5. Добавить свой единственно верный ответ в ответы - не айс, потому что уже могли дать два и более не точных ответа, каждый с репой два и более. И если твой ответ - третий, до него благодарный загугливатель не дойдёт.

**Вопрос:** как автору вопроса, который подрос, да поднабрался опыта показать свой, единственно правильный, короткий и понятный ответ на свой вопрос, так чтобы и зашедшие гарантировано увидели, и ранее ответившие не были обижены?

Comment: #1, или, если так же возможно улучшить вопрос, то новый вопрос+самоответ.

Comment: Почему Вы не рассматриваете вариант, при котором Иван **будет благодарен** разъяснению его ошибок? Вполне может быть, что он просто не подозревает о них, а узнав, прокачает свои знания и поправит личные проекты.

Comment: @nomnoms12 бывает и так. Но чаще чувак обнаруживает -15 к репе. Начинает кидать ответочку. Жалко не свою репу, а чувака который пытался тебе помочь, а ты его так жестоко.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Действительно, люди бывают разные. Скажу за себя — за год сняли галку примерно с пяти моих ответов. И мне обидно. Но обидно не за -15, а за то, что ни один не объяснил мне причину. Считаю, что стоит спокойно объяснить человеку его ошибку. Я бы даже сказал, что это проявление уважения — признак того, что Вы не забыли его ответ. Если Иван выйдет на диалог, то Вам, возможно, даже не придётся снимать галку — просто исправите ответ.

Answer (score 26):

Галочка важна людям, ищущим ответ, т.к. показывает что именно правильно (по мнению автора вопроса и при прочих равных etc).

Засим правильно и полезно написать свой ответ и поставить на него галочку. Если не хотите обижать ранее ответившего - напишите это в ответе. Что, мол, тот ответ имеет ряд проблем и лучше делать так, как в этом ответе потому-то и посему-то.

К сожалению, всем мил не будешь и кто-то всегда уйдёт с неприятным осадком в душе, тут ничего не исправишь. Да и древние считали, что истина дороже друзей.

Comment: А представьте такую картину, с точки зрения отвечающего:
1. Я ответил -> мне поставили галочку -> пятеро мимо крокодилов поставили +1
2. Я рассказал своей бабе, мамке и кошке. Все они похлопали и с моей высокой квалификации (ОН УЖЕ ОБУЧАЕТ!!1) и с моего альтруизма.
3. Пять лет спустя, этот подлец, которому я помог, смеет снимать галку, писать комментарий, что я "весьма поверхностно понимаю предмет".
4. Разве можно жить после этого и кому-то помогать на SO? Оказывается все они подлецы не благодарные!!1.

Comment: Тут от человека все зависит. Я был по обе стороны в подобных ситуациях и ничего, живой. Если мой ответ хуже другого - отлично, я что то новое узнаю

Comment: ИМХО, подобное сюсюканье с чувствами людей вредит качеству базы знаний

Comment: @andreymal видите ли, а без "сюсюканья" мы можем стимулировать людей не отвечать на вопросы. Отсюда снизится количество отвечальщиков. Качество повысится, количество снизится. Или это нормально?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin На мой взгляд, как и почти во всём, нужна золотая середина. Сюсюканья на сайте достаточно в виде поддержания вежливого и уважительного взаимоотношения – это и комфортно, и не вредит поиску правды. А жертвовать истиной и ублажать самодовольство морально незрелых это уже перебор, мы сюда совсем не за этим приходим `(:`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб наверное вы правы. Тем более что очень много людей разделяют вашу позицию. Но я не буду этот ответ принимать. Авось в 2025 году разработчики SO напишут крутой функционал, который нивелирует и эту проблему)

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, я согласен вместе с вами подождать благословенного 2025) Тогда уже люди на Луну вернутся, авось и тут чего поправят)

Comment: Скорее с луны ...

Comment: @AndrewKachalin если ты отвечаешь чтобы потом рассказать мамкке и бабке то **вообще никогда не отвечай**, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Ребята, тут логически всё просто.

[Теорема Гёделя о неполноте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5)

Смысл такой, какой бы вы не приняли набор правил/условий/законов будет существовать задача которая не разрешима в этом наборе. То есть не существует однозначно верного ответа в этом наборе правил. Любая формальная логика не полна либо противоречива.

Пример: Геометрия Евклида, Лобачевского, Римана Если объединить то будет противоречие а каждая не полна по отношению к друг другу.
Смысл простой такое неизбежно и идеальных систем не бывает.

Я думаю главное то что вы нашли верный ответ пусть и не самым приятным путём.

Comment: "тут _**логически**_ всё просто" (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 3):

Правильнее дополнить наполовину правильный ответ. Правило у нас простое: если видите неточность или неполноту можете исправлять/добавлять любой ответ. Тем более, что на ответе стоит галочка, а значит его будут считать правильным.

Что до обид, то о них не стоит беспокоится, все понимают где находятся. А особо ранимым личностям обижающимся на чужие правки, лучше поискать другое место для обид.